# How do I loop through cells in column a to return values from database in each cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a piece of code that allows me to pull data from company server around employee data, such as department and name. I have this set up fine, it uses an LDAP connection as a function, then in another subroutine uses a single cells value as the variable for the function to determine which employee I pull data for and pastes in cells A1-6.

I have gone my entire coding life to date (only couple years) without using a loop. I need help creating a loop that will go through all the values in column a and returns the data as above but pastes next to each unique value that it relates to in columns b and c.

Can't find anything specific enough for this and don't understand loops enough to carry one trying myself before I just brake the code.

Comment: Research for next, do while and while loops. Easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find last row of column A

         For i = 1 To Lastrow '<- Loop from row 1 to last row

            MsgBox .Range("A" & i).Value
            'Here put yout code

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This has genuinely helped me understand how it works, better than a lot of the things I've been reading online. It works, however it doesn't seem to be going on to the next cell.

Comment: If this is helpful vote it to helps others. Check Lastrow value

Comment: Figured it out, was a stupid thing I had in my code and I must admit I'm too embarrassed to say what it was.

Comment: glad to help again!